# I can't get the answer of this problem about radius of convergence

Tags: limits, summation

I have this one:

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {\frac{\ln{(3n^{2}+5)}x^{n}}{n^2 - 3n +5}}
$$

I tried with the classic method:

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {\frac{\ln{(3n^{2}+5)}((n+1)^2 -3(n+1)  + 5)x^{n}}{(n^2 - 3n +5)(\ln{3(n+1)^{2}+5})(x^{n+1})}}
$$

But, I can't get to answer, someone can help me please?

Comment: Again, as in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/856051/compute-radius-of-convergence/856056#856056 you should try the root test, it's much cleaner and more direct.

Comment: For the ratio of logarithmic terms you could use L'Hopital's rule, for the rest see answers to your previous question.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't be taking the infinite sum of the successive ratios.

Comment: Please watch your titles (one can guess you can't get the answer, otherwise you would not ask) and try to make them informative.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

For large values of $n$

$$ {\frac{\ln{(3n^{2}+5)}\Big((n+1)^2 -3(n+1)  + 5\Big)}{(n^2 - 3n +5)\ln\Big({3(n+1)^{2}+5}\Big)}}$$ can be approximated by $$1+\frac{2-\frac{2}{\log (3)+2 \log(n)
   }}{n}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^2\right)$$

Comment: Maybe simpler: For large values of $n$, the ratio ... can be approximated by $1+o(1)$. End of proof.

Comment: For sure ! Simplicity and beauty again and again ! Cheers :)